# Translating WHERE NOT IN or LEFT JOIN into LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, ef-code-first

I have the following domain model setup using EF code first:

```
public class User
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserProcessed> UsersProcessed { get; set; }
}

public class UserProcessed
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public virtual User user { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to translate the following T-SQL query into LINQ and I am having some difficulties:

```
SELECT u.Email
FROM Users u LEFT JOIN UsersProcessed up ON u.Id = up.UserId
WHERE up.UserId IS NULL
AND u.CreatedAt BETWEEN '2011-12-01' AND '2011-12-01'
```

This will return all users that have not been processed (UserId does not exist in UsersProcessed table).

```
IEnumerable<User> users = Database.Set<User>().Where(....).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may not translate to exactly the same query when SQL is produced, but it should do the trick:

```
IEnumerable<User> users = Database.Set<User>().Where(u => !u.UserProcessed.Any()).ToList();
```

Comment: It does `WHERE NOT (EXISTS(SELECT null as [EMPTY] FROM TABLE WHERE t1.id = t0.id))`

Comment: @MikeStewart It should be more or less the same in terms of the costs, so I guess it's good. Thanks for checking out the SQL the query generates!